# How can I return the selected radio button text on a form

Tags: forms

I have two radio buttons on a form for example as below:

() Paul

() James

When I use the follwoing code, I am getting the values 0 or 1 depending on my selection. How can I get **Paul** or **James**? 
Thanks for your help.

```
$chosen =$form_state['values']['name_options'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value you want is not in `$form_state` you can check in the `$form` parameter for the original form definition.

e.g:

```
$chosen = $form['name_options']['#options'][$form_state['values']['name_options']];
```